# Canvas stop recognizing trace Android

Tags: android, view, surfaceview, android-canvas, surfaceholder

Trying to make a canvas that works using MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE. However after the thread is started horizontal lines draw correctly, but none of the other lines work or are sporadic. As soon as I release the event, the lines clear themselves.

[Edit]
It was because the canvas was nested in a ScrollView.

Comment: No one will be interested to read the whole paragraph like this, just explain the main problem and in some easy way.

Comment: Are you adding the new UI elements programatically or through an XML layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that "could" cause that is that you are placing the `SurfaceView` in a layout that's trying to scroll.

Please post your layout code for a better answer.

Comment: That was exactly it! I had it wrapped inside of a scrollview... as soon as that portion was taken out, it worked perfectly! I had no idea something so small would cause such an odd behavior. Thank you!!!!